# Can't get search for modification time to work

Tags: lucene

The example in package `org.apache.lucene.demo` works for text search.
But I can't get it to work using and displaying modification time.
It seems that the field `modified` is handled but no success using it.

Running *SearchFiles* prints hits for

Enter query:

```
+kompl*
```

but nothing here

```
+kompl* +modified:[0 TO 9999999999999]
```

Can someone provide an example for this?

Comment: could you try if modified field is filled with something at least?

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong assumption that file attributes are somehow implicitly available to me.
But ok, I had to do it by myself.

For indexing I added a simple integer

```
  // provide stored date integer to query for [yyyymmdd]
  Date dt = new Date(lastModified);
  int myDays = (dt.getYear()+1900)*100*100 + (dt.getMonth()+1)*100 + dt.getDate();
  doc.add(new IntPoint("moddate", myDays ));
  doc.add(new StoredField("moddateVal", myDays ));
```

For searching I handle this field by an extended parser

```
    public static class QueryParserModdate extends QueryParser {
        public QueryParserModdate(String f, Analyzer a) {
            super(f, a);
        }
        protected Query getRangeQuery(String field, String part1, String part2,
                boolean startInclusive, boolean endInclusive)
                throws ParseException {

            if (field.equalsIgnoreCase("moddate")) {
                int part1Int = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                int part2Int = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                try {
                    part1Int = Integer.parseInt(part1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
...
                Query query = IntPoint.newRangeQuery("moddate", part1Int,
                        part2Int);
                return query;
            }
            return super.getRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive,
                    endInclusive);
        }
```

For sure not beautiful but working for me.